# R: ttest across columns

Tags: r, statistics, aggregate

I have the following dataset (abbreviated below). On occasion, I want to run a t-test (or other test) on a subset of data, for instance, comparing `dcxd` in data with `d=1 & c=1` vs `d=0 & c=0`. The closest I've come is using `aggregate()` to provide the means for these, but have been unable to perform any tests on the data. Any  ideas on how to achieve this?

```
(df <- read.table(header = TRUE, text = "   exp   n s d t   dcxd  brdud    cod
1    1 966 0 1 1  44444  63248  20513
2    1 967 0 0 1  69124 165899 101382
3    1 968 0 0 1 126627 338462 195266
4    1 969 0 1 0  25517  10207   7655
5    1 970 0 0 0  62374  46278  28169
6    1 971 1 1 1  48366  73203  41830
7    1 972 1 0 1  78292 138790  65243
8    1 973 1 1 0  99379  49689  37267
9    1 974 1 0 0  52724   8787   1757
10   2 978 0 0 0  11686   6678   1669"))

#    exp   n s d t   dcxd  brdud    cod
# 1    1 966 0 1 1  44444  63248  20513
# 2    1 967 0 0 1  69124 165899 101382
# 3    1 968 0 0 1 126627 338462 195266
# 4    1 969 0 1 0  25517  10207   7655
# 5    1 970 0 0 0  62374  46278  28169
# 6    1 971 1 1 1  48366  73203  41830
# 7    1 972 1 0 1  78292 138790  65243
# 8    1 973 1 1 0  99379  49689  37267
# 9    1 974 1 0 0  52724   8787   1757
# 10   2 978 0 0 0  11686   6678   1669
```

Comment: try `t.test(df[df$d==1 & df$s==1,'dcxd'],df[df$d==0 & df$s==0 ,'dcxd'])`

Comment: or simply `t.test(dcxd ~ d, data = df[with(df, d - s == 0), ])`

Answer (score 1):

Here are two solutions :

create subsets of `df` :

```
d1<-df[df$d==1 & df$s==1,]
d2<-df[df$d==0 & df$s==0,]
t.test(d1$dcxd,d2$dcxd)
```

or without subsets :

```
t.test(df[df$d==1 & df$s==1,'dcxd'],df[df$d==0 & df$s==0 ,'dcxd'])
```

Same results for both of them

```
Welch Two Sample t-test

data:  df[df$d == 1 & df$s == 1, "dcxd"] and df[df$d == 0 & df$s == 0, "dcxd"]
t = 0.185, df = 2.759, p-value = 0.866
alternative hypothesis: true difference in means is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
 -109662.0  122501.5
sample estimates:
mean of x mean of y 
 73872.50  67452.75
```